# Android option menu inflating cause the SearchView focused

Tags: android

I am buidingl a SearchableActivity which contains the search view.

When user submit a search, the `SearchableActivity` will display the result, at the same time I will add one item in the Option menu name "To Result List" which will redirec to the ResultListActivity which display the search result in a List layout.

The workflow can be descripbed as following:

1 User click the Search icon in the action bar and input something and submit.

2 The `SearchableActivity` receive the query in a new intent, and do the search job.

3 Receive the result, display them. And the most important job, invalidate the Option menu by inflating the menu with a new menu layout file which contain the "To Result List" item.

4 When user hit the  "To Result List", start the `ResultListActivity`.

I have almost made the job:

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private int status = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_searchable);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        switch (status) {
            case 0:
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_default, menu);
                break;
            case 1:
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_2, menu);
                break;
        }
        setupSearchView(menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void setupSearchView(Menu menu) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            performSearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void performSearch(String query) {
        textView.setText(query + " result \n");
        status = 1;
        searchView.clearFocus();
        ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this);
    }
}
```

home_default.xml:

```
...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        com.demo:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        com.demo:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
...
```

home_2.xml:

```
...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        com.demo:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        com.demo:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_toResultList"
        android:title="@string/action_toList"
        com.demo:showAsAction="always"/>
...
```

However, I meet some problems:

1 At the workflow step 3, I will invaldate the option menu to add the new item, however I found that if the menu is inflated again, the `SerchView` will be focused and the Input keyborad will show up, like this:

[image]

As the code shown, I have call the `searchView.clearFocus()` but it seem that it does not work.

And if I comment the line

```
ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this);
```

After search, the screen will be this:

[image]

2 When I change the screen orientation after search , I will got a `NullPointException`  at line `searchView.clearFocus();` and the app will exit.

What's the problem?

Comment: i've the same issue.. and i'm still searching a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Well, to remove the query from your SearchView you must do:

```
searchView.setQuery("", false);
```

To close your SearchView then you must do:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_perfil_search);
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem);
```

Don't forget that when you call invalidateOptionsMenu() Android will trigger the onPrepareOptionsMenu()!