# how to set focused on searchview when Activity are start?

Tags: android, android-activity

i want focused on the searchview when redirect from one activity to other activity 
any suggestion?

thanks in Advance

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580396/android-option-menu-inflating-cause-the-searchview-focused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `searchView.requestFocus()` In the onCreate method of your activity.

Comment: sorry ! its not work                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.SearchView.requestFocus()' on a null object reference

Comment: Have you used findViewById() to get the searchView instance? Can you provide your code here?

Comment: Thanks you! I was looking for this exact command for like a half hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use searchView.requestFocus() in your onCreate method if you want to set the focus only when the activity is created or you can do it in the onStart method it will set it everytime the activity will come to the foreground after it has been stop and not destroy by the system.

Comment: Searchview are in menu, so its first call OncreateView() than call onCreateOptionsMenu() so, it is generate NullPointerException....